# ASP.NET Core - The best way to add lots of records to a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I have an Excel file that contains about 4400 records, I used the following loop to save these records in the database.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddExcellHorse(IFormFile ExcelFile)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await ExcelFile.CopyToAsync(stream);

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
            var rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;

            for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                if (worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value != null)
                {
                    AddExcelHorse viewModel = new AddExcelHorse()
                    {
                        MicrochipCode = worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value?.ToString().Trim() ?? String.Empty,
                        EnHorseName = worksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value?.ToString().Trim() ?? String.Empty,                            
                        EnFatherHorseName = worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value?.ToString().Trim() ?? String.Empty,
                        EnMotherHorseName = worksheet.Cells[i, 4].Value?.ToString().Trim() ?? String.Empty,                                      
                    };
                    if (viewModel.MicrochipCode != null)
                    {
                        if (!_admin.ChechMicrochip(viewModel.MicrochipCode))
                        {
                            _admin.AddExcelHorse(viewModel);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
}
```

When I select the Excel file whose records are recorded, I get the following error.

> [Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out]

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: "Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out" has nothing to do with Sql Server

Comment: use bulk insert. at first add all into an object. then send all to server.

Comment: @Gezgalee Can you give an example with the code?

Comment: try https://entityframework-classic.net/bulk-insert

Answer (score 1):

**AddRangeAsync :**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddExcellHorse(IFormFile ExcelFile)
{
    var dataList = new AddExcelHorse();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
       {
           await ExcelFile.CopyToAsync(stream);

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
        var rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;

        for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            if (worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value != null)
            {
                AddExcelHorse viewModel = new AddExcelHorse()
                {
                    MicrochipCode = worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value?.ToString().Trim() ?? String.Empty,
                    EnHorseName = worksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value?.ToString().Trim() ?? String.Empty,
                    EnFatherHorseName = worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value?.ToString().Trim() ?? String.Empty,
                    EnMotherHorseName = worksheet.Cells[i, 4].Value?.ToString().Trim() ?? String.Empty,
                };
                dataList.Add(viewModel);
            }
        }
        if (dataList.Count > 1)
        {
            _context.TableName.AddRange(dataList);
            _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).